# Beam: writing per window element count with window boundaries

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

For a simple proof-of-concept, I'm trying to window click-data in two minute windows. All I want to do from there is print the per-window count, along with the windows' boundaries to BigQuery. On running my pipeline I keep receiving the following error:

```
org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Insert failed: [{"errors":[{"debugInfo":"","location":"windowend","message":"This field is not a record.","reason":"invalid"}],"index":0}]
```

The pipeline looks like this:

```
// Creating the pipeline
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

// Window items
PCollection<TableRow> counts = p.apply("ReadFromPubSub", PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(options.getTopic()))
.apply("AddEventTimestamps", WithTimestamps.of(TotalCountPipeline::ExtractTimeStamp).withAllowedTimestampSkew(Duration.standardDays(10000)))
        .apply("Window", Window.<String>into(
                FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardHours(options.getWindowSize())))
                .triggering(
                        AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
                                .withLateFirings(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1)))
                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardDays(10000))
                .accumulatingFiredPanes())
        .apply("CalculateSum", Combine.globally(Count.<String>combineFn()).withoutDefaults())
        .apply("BigQueryFormat", ParDo.of(new FormatCountsFn()));

// Writing to BigQuery
counts.apply("WriteToBigQuery",BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                .to(options.getOutputTable())
                .withSchema(getSchema())
.withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));

// Execute pipeline
p.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the BigQuery formatting function, which is implemented as follows:

```
static class FormatCountsFn extends DoFn<Long, TableRow> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c, BoundedWindow window) {
        TableRow row =
                new TableRow()
                        .set("windowStart", window.maxTimestamp().toDateTime())
                        .set("count", c.element().intValue());
        c.output(row);
    }
}
```

As inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366910/how-to-get-the-max-timestamp-of-the-current-sliding-window). Can anyone shed some light on this? Can't seem to get my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the answer this question had nothing to do with beam windowing and was solely related to BigQuery. Writing a DateTime object to a BigQuery row requires a string in the proper yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format, this in contrast to the DateTime object I was providing.